# Dropping the 'have' before a past participle

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-participles

1. We have heard what you told us.
2. We've heard what you told us.
3. We heard what you told us.

As far as I know, the first two are OK. There have been enough discussions here on the subject. The third variation however does not seem right but does seem to be entering into common usage. It sounds better if it's followed by something like "and we did something about it."

Is there a rule covering this?

**Clarification as requested by user @RegDwigнt**

I work in government in Australia. I see these three forms used interchangeably for the same purpose. The first two are, as have been observed, the same for all intents and purposes (only included for completeness as I note that there have been one or two differences of opinion here...).

So:

*"We have heard what you told us and are taking action"*
or even...

*"We have heard what you have told us and are taking action"* (didn't mention that one the first time)

*"We heard what you told us and are taking action"*

Each means - As a result of the feedback that we have received, we may do something.

Comment: In the last example, _heard_ isn't a participle, it's just a verb in the past tense. That changes it from past perfect to simple past, but that's still grammatical.

Comment: This will work with verbs whose past tense form is the same as their past participle, which means every regular verb in English, and quite a few irregular ones.

Comment: You need to understand what a participle is.

Comment: I am perplexed at "does seem to be entering into common usage". It has been in common usage forever. Literally before Modern English even existed.

Comment: The edit to the question doesn't clarify anything for me – I'm still not sure why you think the past simple tense version is incorrect or awkward.

Comment: Guys... 'All three are correct for this usage' would be a perfectly good answer :) and that, in this case, perfect and simple mean exactly the same thing and are interchangeable. As to why I thought #3 sounded odd in this context? It just did - in the context it was used it sounded 'grammatically discordant' but I couldn't think why, hence the question. The comments here so far suggest that it was my perception rather than the speaker that was wrong. Happy with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both Bradd Szonye and John Lawler point out in their comments, your example #3 sounds right because *heard* is the correct simple past tense of *hear.* But let's take an example where the past participle differs from the simple past tense:

> 1. We have known what you did last Walpurgis Night.
> 2. We've known what you did last Walpurgis Night.
> 3. We *known what you did last Walpurgis Night.

Completely omitting *have* from the sentence (as in #3) leaves you with a sentence that few people would consider immediately intelligible. In trying to make sense of it, most people would probably change *known* to *knew* (the simple past tense), rather than supplying the missing *have* needed to establish *known* as a past participle.

Comment: Good job of illustrating the difference.

Comment: Bradd Szonye, I've been reading and enjoying your comments and answers for almost a year, and yet only now do I see that your name has two d's in it. My apologies for this and any other instance in the past when I've misspelled it. (And thanks also for adding the asterisk to my example #3.)

Comment: No worries! It's a very common mistake. Happy to help!

Comment: @SvenYargs, Better to demonstrate with a nonstative.

Answer (score 0):

The first two - in the original and in Sven's reply - are identical:  "We've" = "We have".

Comment: The contraction is what sets them apart—they contain the same words, but they are not identical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Semantically identical.